# Javascript in WordPress won't work because of AJAX form

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, forms, elementor

For a client, I was using a form built with Formidable Forms plugin. In Elementor, I added this piece of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.querySelector('.example').innerHTML = '<img src = "/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/svg1.svg" class="elementor img" alt="example"/><br/><span class="dptitle">example</span>';
</script>
```

This code worked perfectly fine and the SVG was inserted.

However, after changing the form to an AJAX form, the code above is no longer working.

Does anyone have any idea on how this Javascript can be working in an AJAX form?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Can you please describe the term "AJAX form"? Did you mean the form is loading on or after the ajax response?

Comment: @VijayHardaha Submitting the form, or clicking the next step on the form is using AJAX. So the page does not refresh itself.

Comment: So you have a multi-step form? and `.example` class element on next step in which you want to inject the javascript?

Comment: @VijayHardaha Exactly!

Comment: @VijayHardaha next step has '/?&frm_page=2' after the URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `frmPageChanged` js event to inject your js code.

You can see example here
https://formidableforms.com/knowledgebase/javascript-examples/javascript-after-form-submit/#kb-after-another-pages-content-is-shown

So your code should be like this:

```html
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $(document).on("frmPageChanged", function (event, form, response) {
            document.querySelector(".example").innerHTML = '<img src = "/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/svg1.svg" class="elementor img" alt="example"/><br/><span class="dptitle">example</span>';
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You can also use `setTimeout` with your code if there is any problem due to content loading time.

Comment: It immediately worked! Thank you so much, completely missed this...